# Is excersizing up to a sweat when you are sick beneficial, as opposed to only resting?

Tags: common-cold, medical-myths, home-remedies

I feel like I get mixed messages about whether or not it is good to work up a sweat when you catch a cold/flu (anecdotal). ..I get it if you don't want to go to the gym to spread the virus, but hypothetically if you had a home gym, is it good to work out when you have a cold?

Comment: The official recommendation is to continue to exercise when you have a cold, but at reduced intensity that's appropriate for how the cold has affected you. For example,when I had a cold about 7 years ago, I ran at slow jogging speed for 20 minutes and did another 20 minutes brisk walk. Normally I would be running for one hour at a fast pace. If you overreact to a cold by not exercising at all, then after a few days your body will notice that your burning many hundreds of calories less per day, which will then negatively affect appetite and sleep.